# Cant see SQL queries with multiple database landscape

Tags: django, django-queryset, multiple-databases

Django 2.1.7, MySQL. DATABASES config is like:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'auth',
        ...
    },
    'db1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'db1',
        ...
    },
    'db2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'd2',
        ...
    }
}
```

I have various issues with viewing raw SQL queries:

1) Cant print the query of particular queriset:

```
qs = Model.objects.using("db2").filter(...)
print(qs.query)
```

This code drops `ImproperlyConfigured` because it doesnt respect the `.using("db2")` and somewhy check the default db which is empty (Empty default_db is quite okay as said in django docs)

2) When in runtime i open a shell to monitor queries:

```
from django.db import connections
print(connections["db1"].queries)
```

i just see this:

```
[{'sql': 'None', 'time': '0.001'},
 {'sql': 'None', 'time': '0.000'},
 {'sql': 'None', 'time': '0.008'}]
```

`debug=True` is set like said in docs.

Anyone has an experience with this kind of issues woth multiple db?

**EDIT:**
My database routers is configured well as said in the docs. All is good in a runtime, but for debugging purposes i of course need a shell to manually test querysets in different databases.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little bit old topic. But even you have DEBUG set on, but your example shows query with filter. You don't actually call it (lazy). That's why your query is None.

```
from django.db import connections
from django.conf import settings


settings.DEBUG = True
qs = Model.objects.using('mydb').filter()
# still none
print(connections['mydb'].queries)

# example triggering the query
foo = len(objects) # don't call .count() because then query changes
# or example go through it
for o in objects:
    pass
    # do something

# now your query and time is seen
print(connections['mydb'].queries)
```

Answer (score -1):

> The DATABASES setting must configure a default database; any number of
>   additional databases may also be specified.

I find this from [database doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases). So you can not set `default` empty. So you have to set the default by inserting the dummy data.

If you solve the first problem but second problem persists, please let me know.

**Edit:**

> If the concept of a default database doesn’t make sense in the context
>   of your project, you need to be careful to always specify the database
>   that you want to use. Django requires that a default database entry be
>   defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will
>   not be used. To do this, you must set up [DATABASE_ROUTERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE_ROUTERS) for all of
>   your apps’ models, including those in any contrib and third-party apps
>   you’re using, so that no queries are routed to the default database.
>   The following is an example settings.py snippet defining two
>   non-default databases, with the default entry intentionally left
>   empty:

From [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#defining-your-databases).
So you need to config [DATABASE_ROUTERS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DATABASE_ROUTERS).

Comment: Thank you, but seems like this is not like you said. Please read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db. "Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used." Ive pointed this in my question ...

Comment: My database routers is configured properly. Ive added this info in the first post.

Comment: Can you post your database router code and `settings.py`? @AlexeyTrofimov